# How to start/stop function based on entry start stop time

Tags: datetime, time, tkinter-entry

I've some LED lights that I want to turn on from entry box 0600 to 1800, or perhaps start another function from 1800 to 0300. how can I make a function to set so the action is ON during the period between the entry values and off otherwise. I've used Time but I'm running into issues. I don't know if I should convert the entry to Int() and compare but find it doesn't resolve the evening On entry. Any thoughts on this one would be appreciated.

```
LED_time_on_txt = StringVar()
LED_time_on = Entry(control_window, width = 4, bd=5, font= "Arial",14),textvariable=LED_time_on_txt)
LED_time_on.grid(row=3,column=8,sticky=W)
LED_time_off_txt = StringVar()
LED_time_off = Entry(control_window, width = 4, bd=5, font=("Arial",14),textvariable=LED_time_off_txt)
LED_time_off.grid(row=3,column=10,sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out wiht other posts... function looks something like this:

```
now = datetime.now()
timeontxt = LED_time_on_txt.get()
timeofftxt = LED_time_off_txt.get()
time_on = now.replace(hour=int(timeontxt[:2]), 
minute=int(timeontxt[:2]),second=0, microsecond=0)
time_off = now.replace(hour=int(timeofftxt[:2]), minute=int(timeofftxt[:2]), second=0, microsecond=0)
if time_on > time_off:
    time_off = time_off + timedelta(days=1)
if time_on<now<time_off:
    LED_status.config(text="ON")
```